# No module found 'firebase_admin' Raspberry Pi - Raspbian Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, raspbian, firebase-admin

I'm trying to run the firebase admin SDK in python3 on the Raspberry pi but it's not working.

I run (in the console)

```
sudo pip install firebase-admin
```

To install and then attempt to use (in the IDSL)

```
import firebase_admin
```

in Python 3 but I get the no module found error.  What might I be missing?  This is on a fresh install of Raspbian on an old Pi.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out all I needed to do was use the following command instead:

```
sudo pip3 install firebase-admin
```

Comment: Glad it worked out. But please be aware, that using Admin SDK in an end-user or IoT device is usually not recommended due to security implications. Tread carefully.

Comment: the pi is being used to lower costs as a cheap computational device, not used as an end user project

Comment: Lol, sudo is what i missed. Thanks.